# Sending array response in promise callback but the response is blank

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, promise

I am generating an image from google map. This is a promise return method in that I am just looping with the results and storing the result into a new Array variable inside the "then" callback but the response is there but it's not showing in the browser.

Before my google map generating images function was not a promise return function and it was sending the response to browser but it's a promise return function so the response is there but the controller method is not sending a response to the browser.

```
  static providerMapImageGenerator(req, res) {
    let providerArr = []
    ProvidersRepository.getProviderInfoForMapImage()
      .then(providers => {
        providers.forEach(provider => {
          // Generating image against each entr
          MapGenerator.getMapImage(
            provider.latitude,
            provider.longitude,
            provider.name,
            provider.providerId
          )
            .then(res => {
              // Saving record after each entry
              ProviderMap.create({
                providerId: provider.providerId,
                url: res.Location
              })
              // Adding new array for response
              providerArr.push({
                id: provider.providerId,
                url: res.Location,
                lat: provider.latitude,
                long: provider.longitude,
                name: provider.name
              })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err, "err in generating image"))
        })
        // Sending final response against all generated entries to user
        res.send(providerArr) // this is going blank to the browser
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // Sending error response if fails
        res.send(error)
      })
  }
```

I need the providerArr response to display in the browser.

Comment: For loops do not wait for async actions to finish before continuing on to the next iteration. Use `Promise.all` and pass it an array of promises to wait for them all to complete

Comment: how I can resolve this?

Comment: @IsaacVidrine Can you please tell me how to add promise.all in my current code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is going without waiting for promise result. You can use `async/await` with `for of` loop to do what you want as below:

```
ProvidersRepository.getProviderInfoForMapImage()
  .then(async (providers) => {
    for(provider of providers){
      // Generating image against each entr
      let image = await MapGenerator.getMapImage(
        provider.latitude,
        provider.longitude,
        provider.name,
        provider.providerId
      );
      // Saving record after each entry
      await ProviderMap.create({
         providerId: provider.providerId,
         url: res.Location
      });
       // Adding new array for response
      providerArr.push({
          id: provider.providerId,
          url: res.Location,
          lat: provider.latitude,
          long: provider.longitude,
          name: provider.name
         });
     })
    }
    // Sending final response against all generated entries to user
    res.send(providerArr) // this is going blank to the browser
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Sending error response if fails
    res.send(error)
  })
```

PS: Not tested

Comment: for of loop is only for the objects not for arrays. so this solution is not working for me.

Comment: but it's working now after chaning for of to for loop.

Comment: @MuhammadAdil The for...of statement creates a loop iterating over iterable objects, including: built-in String, Array, Array-like objects (e.g., arguments or NodeList), TypedArray, Map, Set, and user-defined iterables. It invokes a custom iteration hook with statements to be executed for the value of each distinct property of the object.

Here is the doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: You are correct. but I tried the for of loop in my code but the loop was not working for me. Not sure why so I tried for loop then.

Comment: My providers result is coming from sequelize model directly. maybe it's not real array-like objects or iterable objects.

Comment: Is this really issue?

Comment: If you call `YourModel.findAll()`, the result must be an array of YourModel

Comment: I am trying to find the exact problem here, my issue resolved by the way. 

`static getProviderInfoForMapImage() {
        // Return promise object after resolving records
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // Find all providers, but for now only five for testing
            Provider.findAll({
                attributes: ['providerId', 'name', 'latitude', 'longitude'],
                limit: 2
            })
            .then(res => resolve(res))
            .catch(error => reject(error));
        });   
    }`
This is my method for getting records.

Comment: I got the issue, `for(let provider of providers){ // }` that's the mistake we did here. :)

Answer (score 1):

Amadou's answer is correct, but it does its processing sequentially instead of in parallel, waiting for each `MapGenerator.getMapImage()` to finish before firing another request. With some modification, you can fire all of your requests at the same time and wait for all of them to complete.

```
  static providerMapImageGenerator(req, res) {
    let providerArr = []
    ProvidersRepository.getProviderInfoForMapImage()
      .then(providers => {
        return Promise.all(providers.map(provider => {
          // Generating image against each entr
          return MapGenerator.getMapImage(  // ** actually return the promise so
            provider.latitude,              // ** Promise.all gets an array of promises
            provider.longitude,
            provider.name,
            provider.providerId
          )
            .then(res => {
              // Saving record after each entry
              ProviderMap.create({
                providerId: provider.providerId,
                url: res.Location
              })
              // Adding new array for response
              providerArr.push({
                id: provider.providerId,
                url: res.Location,
                lat: provider.latitude,
                long: provider.longitude,
                name: provider.name
              })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err, "err in generating image"))
        })
        // Sending final response against all generated entries to user
        .then(() => res.send(providerArr)); // this is going blank to the browser
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // Sending error response if fails
        res.send(error)
      })
  }
```

Comment: with above promise.all my response would be the same as I wanted